# domToPdf is blank

Tags: angular

I am using the dom-to-pdf library, repository here: https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf

I have the following method that:

1. Hits the server for data
2. Dynamically builds a variable based on that data
3. Call `domToPdf` to print the DOM

The component's HTML layer uses `*ngFor` to dynamically populate the DOM based on the variable is step 2.

This is my method:

```js
generateReport(): void {
  let bloodPressureFilter = `${this.bloodPressure.readDateFrom ? `ReadDate_GreaterEqual=${encodeURIComponent(this.datePipe.transform(this.bloodPressure.readDateFrom, 'YYYY-MM-dd'))}` : ''}`;
  bloodPressureFilter = `${bloodPressureFilter ? '&' : ''}${this.bloodPressure.readDateTo ? `ReadDate_LessEqual=${encodeURIComponent(this.datePipe.transform(this.bloodPressure.readDateTo, 'YYYY-MM-dd'))}` : ''}`;
  let sugarFilter = `${this.sugar.readDateFrom ? `ReadDate_GreaterEqual=${encodeURIComponent(this.datePipe.transform(this.sugar.readDateFrom, 'YYYY-MM-dd'))}` : ''}`;
  sugarFilter = `${sugarFilter ? '&' : ''}${this.sugar.readDateTo ? `ReadDate_LessEqual=${encodeURIComponent(this.datePipe.transform(this.sugar.readDateTo, 'YYYY-MM-dd'))}` : ''}`;
  let weightFilter = `${this.weight.readDateFrom ? `ReadDate_GreaterEqual=${encodeURIComponent(this.datePipe.transform(this.weight.readDateFrom, 'YYYY-MM-dd'))}` : ''}`;
  weightFilter = `${weightFilter ? '&' : ''}${this.weight.readDateTo ? `ReadDate_LessEqual=${encodeURIComponent(this.datePipe.transform(this.weight.readDateTo, 'YYYY-MM-dd'))}` : ''}`;
  forkJoin({
    bloodPressures: this.bloodPressureService.query(bloodPressureFilter),
    sugars: this.sugarService.query(sugarFilter),
    weight: this.weightService.query(weightFilter)
  }).subscribe(results => {
    this.records = [];
    const bloodPressures = this.bloodPressure.visible ? results.bloodPressures : [];
    const sugars = this.sugar.visible ? results.sugars : [];
    const weights = this.weight.visible ? results.weight : [];

    bloodPressures.forEach(bloodPressure => {
      const grouppedObject = this.records.find(record => record.entryDate === bloodPressure.ReadDate);
      if (!grouppedObject) {
        this.records.push({
          entryDate: bloodPressure.ReadDate,
          bloodPressures: [ bloodPressure ]
        });
      } else {
        grouppedObject.bloodPressures = grouppedObject.bloodPressures ?? [];
        grouppedObject.bloodPressures.push(bloodPressure);
      }
    });
    sugars.forEach(sugar => {
      const grouppedObject = this.records.find(record => record.entryDate === sugar.ReadDate);
      if (!grouppedObject) {
        this.records.push({
          entryDate: sugar.ReadDate,
          sugars: [ sugar ]
        });
      } else {
        grouppedObject.sugars = grouppedObject.sugars ?? [];
        grouppedObject.sugars.push(sugar);
      }
    });
    weights.forEach(weight => {
      const grouppedObject = this.records.find(record => record.entryDate === weight.ReadDate);
      if (!grouppedObject) {
        this.records.push({
          entryDate: weight.ReadDate,
          weights: [ weight ]
        });
      } else {
        grouppedObject.weights = grouppedObject.weights ?? [];
        grouppedObject.weights.push(weight);
      }
    });
    const today = new Date();
    const element = document.getElementById('report');
    const options = {
      filename: `${this.datePipe.transform(today, 'yMMdhhmmssa')}.pdf`
    };
    domToPdf(element, options, () => {
      console.log('PDF exported');
      this.records = [];
    });
  });
}
```

And this is my component:

```html
<div id="report" *ngIf="records">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let record of records">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{record.entryDate | date:'MMMM d, y'}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p *ngFor="let sugar of record.sugars">At {{sugar.ReadTime | date:'h:mm a'}}, I had a blood sugar reading of {{sugar.Reading}}.</p>
      <p *ngFor="let bloodPressure of record.bloodPressures">At {{bloodPressure.ReadTime | date:'h:mm a'}}, I had a blood pressure reading of {{bloodPressure.Systolic}}/{{bloodPressure.Diastolic}}.</p>
      <p *ngFor="let bloodPressure of record.weights">At {{weight.ReadTime | date:'h:mm a'}}, I weighed {{weight.Weight}}.</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

The issue (I think) is that because it is taking the document too long to dynamically generate the HTML it is downloading a blank PDF. The reason I say this is because if I remove the code above where I set the options and call `domToPdf` and replace my HTML with `<h2>TEST</h2>` then a PDF is exported with the content.

Is there a work around so that the massaged data gets exported?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing domToPDF immediately after the view updates, chances are the element is still blank, there are couple of options to solve this issue:

1. Either user [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to check when the element you want to export to pdf is available in the dom
2. Try executing the domToPDF in the next tick by using setTimeout:

   ```
    setTimeout( ()=> {
       domToPdf(element, options, () => {
          console.log('PDF exported');
          this.records = [];
        });
    }, 0);
   ```